# Expressing "It's totally not ok!" vs "It's not totally ok."

Tags: word-choice, emphasis

In English saying "It's totally not ok!" emphasizes that the whole thing (whatever the subject is in the sentence) is not ok and that it is clearly very not ok because of how completely not ok it is.

When you say "It's not totally ok." you are implying part of it is ok but part of it is bad enough that it shouldn't have happened.

I tried to find different translations of these but they both turn up
全然大丈夫じゃないよ

Is there a way to make this distinction in Japanese or is it implied by context and tone?

Comment: Theoretically "not totally ok" → "全然（ではなく｜じゃなく）大丈夫だ"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short answer is no. It depends on tone and also on personal perceptions, I suppose. As such, note this answer is to an extent subjective.

The obvious translation 全然大丈夫じゃない sounds *totally not ok* partly because it parses as a pattern 全然...ない, emphatically denying '...' (more literally corresponds to *not ok at all*). But it *is* ambiguous with *not totally ok*.

For *not totally ok*, 全然大丈夫(pause)ではない<sup>1</sup> works for me, but it may depend on how you say it. Note that は often appears for partially denying something (e.g. *money is not everything* : 金がすべてで**は**ない). More explicitly clarifying *not totally*, you can use something more clumsy: まったく大丈夫というわけではない<sup>2</sup>, which has no ambiguity with *totally not ok* (that 全然大丈夫ではない has).

---

<sup>1</sup> Since there's a pause, ではない sounds better (to me)

<sup>2</sup> 全然大丈夫というわけではない is ok, too, but I think I myself would use まったく.

Comment: Thank you for all the information.  I'm still having a lot of trouble grasping implied meaning on a more intuitive level with how words are ordered and joined.  

The different ideas made by small changes in an English sentence sometimes helps me understand a little more when I see how the distinction is made in Japanese.

Things like "He will arrive soon," or "He should arrive soon," or He might arrive soon," or "He will arrive soon I guess," can imply certainty or doubt either in the speakers knowledge of the subject or the subject itself that add to the tone and context.